# How to use timeout attribute with post method in jQuery ajax request?

Tags: jquery, ajax, timeout

I've a following function:

```
function mark_unmark_user_answer(targ, answer, answer_id, test_id, test_type, question_no, module_url) {
    if(checked==targ){
    targ.checked=false;
    checked=false;
  } else {
    checked=targ;
  }

    $.post(module_url, {'test_id':test_id, 'question_no':question_no, 'op':'mark_ans', 'test_type':test_type, 'answer_no':answer, 'answer_id':answer_id}, function(data) { 
        if(jQuery.trim(data)=='unmark_ans') {
          $('input[type="radio"]').removeAttr('checked');
          $('#display_'+question_no).removeClass('green');
          $('#display_'+question_no).removeClass('blue');
          $('#display_'+question_no).addClass('orange');
        } else {
            //$('#mark_review').val('Mark'); 
            $('#display_'+question_no).removeClass('orange');
            $('#display_'+question_no).removeClass('blue');
            $('#display_'+question_no).addClass("green");
            $('#mark_review').attr('disabled', false);  
        }
        var total_questions = $('#total_questions').val();
        test_question_attempted_count( total_questions );    
    });
}
```

I want to assign time-out of **30 seconds** to this function. So if the response for the ajax request is not received within 30 seconds then the alert message saying that "Your internet connection has some problem" should appear. Otherwise normal function should get execute.

Can anyone help on this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10):

Try use

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: your_url_request,
    data: {field: value, field_2: value_2},    
    timeout: 1000,
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        if(textStatus==="timeout") {
           //do something on timeout
        } 
    }});
```

You can has more information in:
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 6):

You can set defaults for Ajax request in `$.ajaxSetup` method like this

```
function mark_unmark_user_answer(targ, answer, answer_id, test_id, test_type, question_no, module_url) {
    if(checked==targ){
    targ.checked=false;
    checked=false;
  } else {
    checked=targ;
  }
$.ajaxSetup({
type: 'POST',
timeout: 30000,
error: function(xhr) {
    $('#display_error')
    .html('Error: ' + xhr.status + ' ' + xhr.statusText);
                     }
             })

$.post(module_url, {'test_id':test_id, 'question_no':question_no, 'op':'mark_ans', 'test_type':test_type, 'answer_no':answer, 'answer_id':answer_id}, function(data) { 
    if(jQuery.trim(data)=='unmark_ans') {
      $('input[type="radio"]').removeAttr('checked');
      $('#display_'+question_no).removeClass('green');
      $('#display_'+question_no).removeClass('blue');
      $('#display_'+question_no).addClass('orange');
    } else {
        //$('#mark_review').val('Mark'); 
        $('#display_'+question_no).removeClass('orange');
        $('#display_'+question_no).removeClass('blue');
        $('#display_'+question_no).addClass("green");
        $('#mark_review').attr('disabled', false);  
    }
    var total_questions = $('#total_questions').val();
    test_question_attempted_count( total_questions );    
});
}
```

Answer (score -4):

Since jQuery 1.2 you are able to provide all parameters to [jQuery.post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) via PlainObject.

So, your snippet can be rewritten like this:

```
$.post({ url: module_url, data: { … })
```

Answer (score -10):

1. Just Open **jquery.js** File.
2. Now Find `jQtimeout`
3. Default Set Time is `60000` Milisecond, Replace with Your Time In Milisecond `120000` for `120` Seconds
4. `var jQtimeout = 120000;` Look like This
5. It's Done.

Enjoy with Shivesh Chandra :)